# WordPress Gutenberg selenium

Tags: c#, wordpress, selenium-webdriver

How can I write title in Gutenberg using selenium?

I was trying to add a simple title to the new blog post.

```cs
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
           
// enter your configurations here 
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post-new.php");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_login")).SendKeys("admin");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("user_pass")).SendKeys("password");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("wp-submit")).Click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(d => driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Displayed);
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("editor-canvas");
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("h1")).SendKeys("Hello");`
```

Comment: ...doesn't your posted code work... or not? You haven't told us what problems you're having.

Comment: Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to locate element: h1

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: Yes, Dai. However, I can't find a solution for the error message.

Comment: _"I can't find a solution for the error message."_ - Sorry, but what you've said tells me that you don't actually understand the error message then... because the error-message _already specifically tells you what the problem is_ - may I ask what difficulties you are having with converting the error-message into troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you sure the page actually contains a H1 element? The error message says to me that it doesn't.